# How to get IntelliJ IDEA to self-close HTML5 empty elements?

Tags: html, intellij-idea

The project I'm working on has a standard that HTML5 code must also be well formed XML. This requirement is built into automated tests. This means empty elements like `img`, `link`, `br`, `hr`, ... must have a `/>` closing delimiter - not just a `>`.

For example:

1) good: `<img src="foo.png" alt="stuff" />`

2) bad:  `<img src="foo.png" alt="stuff">`

I'm using Intellij IDEA 2018.2. I have Emmet enabled. To create an img element I type `img` followed by a TAB. Emmet expands this to `<img src="" alt="">` but that's not well formed XML. I want it to automatically self-close resulting in `<img src="" alt="" />`. I've also tried CTRL+SPACE auto-complete with the same result.

**Question**: *How do I get Intellij IDEA to automatically self close HTML5 empty elements?*

This is a simple question and I've done internet searches and looked at Intellij Settings and documentation but still haven't found an answer. Maybe I'm just missing it ...

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 tags like `<br>` or `<img>` do not require a `"/ "` for closing them like `<br/>` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element,
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements).

However, you can easily change current behavior in **Settings | Editor | Live Template | Zen Html | br/img** by modifying the templates accordingly:

[image]

Comment: That's a possible workaround. But it doesn't preserve the trailing space before the start tag end-delimter and it requires the developer to update every Zen HTML empty element manually. I'm hoping for a global setting like: "Self close empty elements". 

Also, yes I know HTML5 does not REQUIRE empty elements to be closed. However, a valid HTML5 document may also be a well formed XML document and that's a requirement for this project, and a good one at that because it helps detect markup problems before the webapp gets deployed and enforces a consistent coding style.

Comment: live templates are formatted according to code style preferences on applying; to ensure that there is a white space before the start tag end-delimter, enable **In empty tag** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML |Other, Spaces**

Answer (score 0):

you may also write `img/` to expand to a self-closing element